# Angular version 4- Running on IE 11, unable to locate polyfills.ts

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I am attempting to run an angular application (version 4) on IE11.  I have found a solution that I need to uncomment lines from polyfills.ts

However, I am unable to locate that file.

Is it possible that I do not have that file, if so what is the best course of action to take in order for the application to be able to run on IE11?

I am getting the following error: "**Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Add the error to the question. Also what file are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer by combining a couple of answers.

First, I never did find the polyfills.ts file, it is not in my project but I did not need it.

In order to fix this problem, I went to my boot-client.ts file and added the following three lines at the top:

```cpp
 import 'reflect-metadata';
 import "core-js/client/shim"; 
 import 'zone.js';
```

This answer was provided to another question, however I added these lines to the boot-client.ts rather than the polyfills.ts file since I did not have that in my project.

Comment: And don't forget to add typings: 
`npm install --save @types/core-js`

Comment: This worked for me too when using the aspnet core 2.0 angular template.  However I only had to add `import "core-js/client/shim"` as described in the answer to my boot.browser.ts.